# Stuck at “/dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files […] ” in ubantu 20.x

Tags: boot, networking

I have different answers, but not able to understand, please help me with this and how can I use the terminal even I got stuck in booting

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What are the different answers?

Comment: Welcome! Please **edit** your question and add the **exact** Ubuntu version and flavor, and include any links to questions and sources you used, as well as any commands you've tried. This would really help us to help you better.